# Se puede obtener el texto de un teclado o escaner bluetooth

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo un escaner que se conecta vía bluetooth pero necesito capturar lo que escanea cuando la pantalla esta apagada.

**¿Se puede hacer con un BroadcastReceiver? o alguna idea de como empezar**

Answer (score 3):

La solución para este requerimiento fue colocar la pantalla en modo desbloqueo ninguno, implemente el método `onKeyIme()` y es muy importante obtener el texto en el `event.ACTION_UP` ya que el `event.ACTION_DOWN` es el que desbloquea la pantalla por lo tanto la entrada del carácter se pierda.

```
    if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK && getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN ){
     Log.i(EntregaStreetActivity.class.getName(),"back");
    }else if( event.getAction() == event.ACTION_UP){
     barcodebuffer += Character.toString((char) event.getUnicodeChar());
     Log.i(EntregaStreetActivity.class.getName(), "filterBarcodeKeys Char: "+ Character.toString((char) event.getUnicodeChar()));
    }
```